# I have an issue with authorization tokens on openshift

Tags: authorization, openshift, token

I am developing a web app on openshift. Today I got this error when I did a port forwarding command:

"Your authorization token has expired. Please sign in now to continue on openshift.redhat.com.
Password:"

When I enter my openshift password nothing happens.
does anyone know what's going on?

Comment: Token expires regularly for security reasons. Have you tried deleting all ssh keys on the openshift + your local machine? After deleting them, try running `rhc setup`

Comment: Hi Ryan, thanks for your reply. Would you be able to tell me how to reactivate the token? When I enter my password and press enter nothing at all happens...

Comment: I thought you cannot reactivate token. You need to generate new tokens. Usually, when you perform any rhc operation, it will prompt for password and generate token automatically. It seems that's not working for you. Did you try using `rhc setup` to automatically generate and upload ssh key pair and token? Also you can try generating the ssh key pair yourself and upload the public key to openshift web console.

Comment: I tried the rhc setup but it won't work...but thanks for your help. I'll try and generate the key again. I used putty the first time.. I just watched a video in YouTube: I'll do the same thing tomorrow and post here if I still have issues.

Comment: I had similar problem, there were several things I had to make sure: 1. remove all ssh public keys on openshift server; 2. remove all ssh keys stored in my local machine (usually .ssh folder); 3. configure the server correctly if you have your own openshift hosting (openshift.company.com); 4. ruby, git versions (sometimes higer ruby versions have issues with openshift) 5. reinstall rhc; That fixed my issue

Comment: @Ryan. Thanks for your help, it worked fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I'll try reinstalling the whole thing eventually, I remember having issues during the installation, maybe that'll fix everything.
Thank you mate. I tried to upvote your comment but it doesn't work: I appreciated your help though.

Answer (score 3):

I had such problem when I have tried to execute commands through git bash console. Try a common console!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the git-bash, rhc commands are currently behaving oddly.  Open git-cmd, run:

rhc ssh -a *gear*

from there, and once you have logged in with a password, voila, you have a new token.

You can also do most of this by adding a new authorization token from the web console, and then adding it to git with :

rhc apps --token *new-token*

Answer (score 0):

> When I enter my openshift password nothing happens

I had this issue too.

Rather than waiting for the password prompt, send your password when you run the `rhc` command, like this:

```
rhc apps -p {password}
```